# How to use aggregation value on document update using script in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to update a document field based on id using script. The value of that field should be MAX(field) * 2. For example consider the following index

```
PUT /my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "cost": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Document will be created with only **name** field value

```
POST /my-index/_doc/sp1
{
  "name": "Shirt"
}
```

Once this document was created, I want to update this document with **cost** value as maximum value of cost in that index (max(cost) * 2). I tried this logic using update API as follows

```
POST /my-index/_doc/sp1
{
  "script" : {
    "source": "ctx._source.cost = Math.max(doc['cost'].value) * 2"
  }
}
```

But I couldn't able to achieve this. Encountered the following error

```
"caused_by" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "static method [java.lang.Math, max/1] not found"
      }
```

How to achieve this scenario

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. The [`_update` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) (which you're **not using** in your example by the way), only allows you to update a document in **its own context**. You don't have access to any other document, only to the document itself (via `ctx._source` or `doc`) and the script parameters (via `params`).

There's no way to perform an aggregation on the whole index and update a specific document with the result. You need to do this in two steps from your client application (first query for aggregation results + then index the result into a document) or via the [transform API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-apis.html) but the latter works in its own way.